# How to check if the column is empty or not in csv , if column is not empty than print data else print something

Tags: php, csv, highcharts

actually i am doing highcharts project which i am doing dynamically in php using csv file data,

this is the code fetching the csv file column wise data:

```
<?php       
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    $i=0;

    $len = count(file('test.csv'));


    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            if($i==$len - 1){

                echo $i." ".$data[1]." ".$data[5];

                }  
                    else if(!empty($data[5])){

                        echo $i." ".$data[1]." ".$data[5];
                    }
                    else{

                    echo $i." ".$data[1];


                }
        $i++;
    }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

this is the csv file without having the 5th column :

```
13-Jan  98.45   98.99   98.99   99.04
13-Feb  98.49   98.97   98.97   99.06
13-Mar  98.74   99.02   99.02   99.09
13-Apr  98.47   98.74   98.74   98.82
13-May  98.17   98.53   98.53   98.61
13-Jun  98.26   98.53   98.53   98.6
13-Jul  98.2    98.62   98.62   98.68
13-Aug  98.08   98.6    98.6    98.66
13-Sep  98.35   98.61   98.61   98.69
13-Oct  98.24   98.82   98.82   98.9
13-Nov  98.59   98.95   98.95   99.03
13-Dec  98.67   98.98   98.98   99.06
14-Jan  98.93   99.15   99.15   99.23
14-Feb  99.01   99.19   99.19   99.27
14-Mar  99.1    99.3    99.3    99.37
14-Apr  98.95   99.2    99.2    99.27
14-May  98.57   98.82   98.82   98.87
14-Jun  98.26   98.5    98.5    98.54
```

In the above csv file i am facing the issue.

This is the csv file with 5th column :

```
13-Jan  98.45   98.99   98.99   99.04   
13-Feb  98.49   98.97   98.97   99.06   
13-Mar  98.74   99.02   99.02   99.09   
13-Apr  98.47   98.74   98.74   98.82   
13-May  98.17   98.53   98.53   98.61   
13-Jun  98.26   98.53   98.53   98.6    
13-Jul  98.2    98.62   98.62   98.68   power issue
13-Aug  98.08   98.6    98.6    98.66   
13-Sep  98.35   98.61   98.61   98.69   
13-Oct  98.24   98.82   98.82   98.9    
13-Nov  98.59   98.95   98.95   99.03   
13-Dec  98.67   98.98   98.98   99.06   flood
14-Jan  98.93   99.15   99.15   99.23   
14-Feb  99.01   99.19   99.19   99.27   
14-Mar  99.1    99.3    99.3    99.37   
14-Apr  98.95   99.2    99.2    99.27   
14-May  98.57   98.82   98.82   98.87   
14-Jun  98.26   98.5    98.5    98.54
```

in the above csv file the graph is plotting correctly:

and this is the jsfiddle link :

http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/3/

In the above php code, i am facing one issue that is when the column is empty the graph is plotting on the graph and if the column contains one value than the graph is plotting.

This is example screenshot that i am facing the issue when i am inspect the element in browser and for the above php code this is the screen shot :

[image]

IN the above screen shot the graph is not plotting when i am inspect element this is the same issue i am getting in browser.

And how to print if the column is empty the the graph has to plot according to the csv coluumn values .

please help ,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all, you can make your loop much more streamlined:

```
$chart_data = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
 $chart_data[] = array (
  'x'    = strtotime($data[0]) * 1000,       //add a javascript friendly epoch time stamp as x value
  'y'    = $data[1],                         //pass the y data value
  'note' = !empty($data[5]) ? $data[5] : ''  //if there is a value, pass it; else pass empty string
 );
}
$chart_data = json_encode($chart_data); //echo this variable in your data parameter for you chart
```

Secondly, you can use the timestamp passed in the above example to make your x axis type 'datetime' and avoid using clunky date categories.

If there is more to your question, you'll have to clarify, as it is not entirely clear where your difficulty is based on your post.

Comment: k , and where i am getting error means , if you please open the link that i have given above in this link : http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/3/    if you remove the values for the extprop:''   and than load in your localhost or in the jsfiddle than the graph will not display...

Comment: remove the values for  extprop: 'power issue' , ...    replace with extprop:'' and load the graph ..the graph is plotting ...this is the issue i am facing...please observe

Comment: I am not experiencing the problem you describe, using your example:  http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/13/

Comment: yes, if you remove the remaining values for extprop in series ....and load the graph ...it is'nt loading

Comment: HI , jibriggs....i have seen you jsfiddle ...please replace all extprop with  extprop:'' and load the graph ...or if any changes in php code ..how to modify in the csv code ...with empty column and non empty column....

Comment: the issue is not in the jsfiddle but the issue is in php code that i have written , if else if condition....the 5th column is empty than it has to print the 1st and 2nd column  other wise  it has to print the 1st and 2nd and 5th column....this is the problem i am facing when i fetch the csv data ...please help

Comment: all instances replaced with '', and it still works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/14/  Did you try the PHP set up I suggested? What did/didn't work?